# Making a link clickable while scrolling

Tags: html, scroll, hyperlink, clickable

I have a bottom navigation menu and I would like the links to be clickable while one is scrolling the screen. I have noticed that you have to have the screen completely still atm, which can be annoying on a smartphone. Is that possible to achieve?

Thanks in advance.